# Change size of ChildFragment from ParentFragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have a fragment(Info1) inside another one(Informacion), the idea is to change the size of Info1 from the code of Informacion and i dont have any idea of how do it.

I have this in Informacion, making that the layout of Info1 change to fill the mobile screen. The problem is that im taking all the layout of Informacion on the Click Listener to make this, i just want take the area of Info1.

Later, i want to make the same with all the other fragment that i want to add inside Informacion.

Im so noobie in Android Studio and Java so please, be patient.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_informacion, container, false);
    final LinearLayout XX = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.LinearInfo1);

    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean T = false;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (T == false) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                param.weight = 0;
                XX.setLayoutParams(param);
                T=true;
            }
            else{
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                param.weight = 1;
                XX.setLayoutParams(param);
                T=false;
            }
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```